# Prove that If $f$ and $h$ commute and $h$ is nilpotent, then $f+h$ and $f$ have the same characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, characteristic-polynomial

let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ ($\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$).
and $f$ and $h$ two vector space endomorphisms of $V$, such as that : $h$ is nilpotent and $f \circ h = h\circ f$.
Prove that $f + h$ and $f$ have the same characteristic polynomial.
I first proved that all eigenvalues of $f$ are also eigenvalues of $f+h$, but even if I prove that they have the same spectrum, it wouldn't mean they both have the same characteristic polynomial, so how should I proceed?

Comment: Is $V$ restricted to be finite dimensional?

Comment: Yes I forgot to include it, but would a characteristic polynomial make any sense in the other case?

Comment: $V$ admits a basis in which both $f$ and $h$ are represented by upper-triangular matrices. (This can be done for arbitrary commuting linear operators $f$, $h$ over $\mathbb{C}$). The characteristic polynomial of an upper-triangular matrix can be easily read off the diagonal, and furthermore since $h$ is nilpotent its diagonal is zero.

Comment: @AymaneLazarus : I've never looked into characteristic power series for the infinite case.  The existence of Weierstrass factorization makes me think it isn't always hopeless.  However, the tendency toward continuous connected components of spectrum make me think that such a power series is not particularly generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $h^m=0$ for some $m$, and let $N>m$ be so large that $\ker (f-\lambda)^{N-m} = \ker (f-\lambda)^{N-m+1}= \ldots =\ker (f-\lambda)^N$ is already stabilized.

As they commute, we have
$$
(f-\lambda + h)^N =
\sum_{k=0}^m {N\choose k} h^k (f-\lambda)^{N-k}=
\big(\ldots\big)(f-\lambda)^{N-m}.
$$
So we have
$$
\ker(f-\lambda)^{N} = \ker(f-\lambda)^{N-m} \subseteq \ker(f-\lambda +h)^N
$$
so any vector that lies in the null-space of $(f-\lambda)^N$ also lies in the null space of $(f-\lambda+h)^N$. Vice versa, $f$ can be expressed as $(f+h)-h$, so using the same argument, the null-space of $(f-\lambda)^N$ and $(f+h-\lambda)^N$ coincide. So the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ is the same.

Comment: I don't see how the identity provides : " any vector that lies in the null-space of $(f-\lambda)^N$also lies in the null space of $(f-\lambda+h)^N$." Normally only the null-space of $(f-\lambda)^{N-m}$ verifies this property. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Correct, but if $N$ is large enought, then $\ker(f - \lambda)^N = \ker(f - \lambda)^{N-m}$. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that $\det(f-\lambda I)=\det(f+h-\lambda I)$, provided $f$ commutes with $h$ and $h$ is nilpotent.
\begin{align}
        \det(f-\lambda I-h)&=\det((f-\lambda I)(I-h(f-\lambda)^{-1})) \\
           &= \det(f-\lambda I)\det(I-h(f-\lambda)^{-1}).
\end{align}
So, the conjecture is equivalent to showing $\det(I-k)=1$ for all a nilpotent $k$. And this follows because the Jordan canonical form for $I-k$ is upper triangular with all $1$'s along the diagonal.